# open layers & typescript : Event.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: javascript, typescript, openlayers

i'm trying to use open layers v7.2.2 with typescript.
{without typescript the code works as expected}

```
function OnMapClick(Event : MapBrowserEvent<UIEvent>)
{
  Event.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(Event.pixel, function(CurrentFeature : Feature) 
  {
  ...
  }
}
```

error :
Type error: Argument of type '(CurrentFeature: Feature) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(arg0: FeatureLike, arg1: Layer<Source, LayerRenderer>, arg2: SimpleGeometry) => void'.
Types of parameters 'CurrentFeature' and 'arg0' are incompatible.
Type 'FeatureLike' is not assignable to type 'Feature'.
Type 'RenderFeature' is missing the following properties from type 'Feature': on, once, un, geometryName_, and 40 more.

any help would be much appreciated.
:-)

Comment: The method can handle both a `Feature` from vector layers and `RenderFeature` from vector tile layers.  `FeatureLike` is the correct declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to declare the type of inline function use this:

```js
function OnMapClick(Event : MapBrowserEvent<UIEvent>)
{
  Event.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(Event.pixel, function(CurrentFeature) 
  {
  ...
  }
}
```